# Boolean modifier doesn't work on Archimesh

Tags: boolean-modifier, archimesh-add-on

I'm making a log cabin in Blender, following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ne2JF8BogCw), but the Boolean modifier only says: *Cannot execute... on mesh objects*.

[image: I'm trying to add a door using Archimesh add-on]

What should I do?

Comment: first you should tell us how you made it, that you could enter a collection into the boolean modifier!?

Comment: @Chris Just by regularly switching _Operand Type_ from _Object_ to _Collection_?

Comment: must have been tired yesterday :D

Answer (score 1):

the reason is exactly, what the error says: you can only use mesh objects for boolean modifier. But in your collection are non-mesh objects. As Gordon commented - your collections contains empties, which aren't meshes, which Blender's boolean modifier doesn't like that much.

Comment: +1 That's exactly the solution I'd say and the screenshot _does_ show it. Next to the name of the collection "Boolean" the icons tell us there are 4 empties and 13 mesh objects in the collection. And those empties will be the reason for this error.

Comment: you are right...tired today as well :D